# Selenium chrome driver is not getting launched

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:115) at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.(ChromeDriver.java:111) at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:104) at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:91) at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:46) at Selenium_Automation.Browser_launch.main(Browser_launch.java:13) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: Seems like your classpath is missing the guava library. Make sure your project dependencies are correct. usually it is recommended to use Gradle or Maven for dependency management instead of manually downloading JAR files. Then an error like you got is unlikely to happen.

Comment: Should describe a bit about the context/situation